# I want 2 for loop -> 1 for loop C

Tags: c, for-loop

I am solving algorithm problem.

It is elements in array, pair -> one value;

I input array's size and add value.

i solve this problem but i meet time complexity problem at biggggg number - n

how can i solve this time complexity problem?

i try to solve one for loop but can't well

plz help me

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int n,m,i,j;
    int count=0;
    scanf("%d %d",&n, &m);
    int array[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d",&array[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=i;j<n;j++){
            if(m==array[i]+array[j]){
                count++;
        }}
    }
    printf("%d",count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: sort the array. Then perform one loop with two indices, one from the beginning of the array, one from the end of the array. Global complexity: O(n logn), for sorting. Second step: O(n).

Comment: Note that in your solution, you allow to add a number to itself (`i = j`). Is it on purpose?

Comment: first what i use sort argorithm  I think quick is better right? second. i purpose `j=i` is last index element not compare

Comment: Using [qsort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) is fine of course.

Comment: Did you test your code? i guess it will count `5+5=10` as a correct solution. Use `j=i+1` if you want to avoid it.

Comment: umm i test that but i'll try again

Comment: I sort and fix 'j=i+1' but still i meet time complexity will i fix for loop?

Comment: @Damien Your solution works only if the given array has distinct numbers. Try the second step you suggested with `array = {-2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 8}` and the sum to make, `sum = 6`

Comment: @writedowntheanswer Do you know hashing? you can try looking it up and then think of a solution which runs in O(nlogn) time. Try it yourself first. If you still stuck then maybe I can post full code as an asnwer.

Comment: Look at my first comment. After sorting, you need one while loop only `while(left < right) { ..}`, with two indices `left` and `right`, initialised respectively to `0` and `n-1`. etc.

Comment: @risingStark thank you i'ii try that

Comment: @Damien umm I don't think I'm good enough. I'll try more.

Comment: @Damien Yeah, I know. You are suggesting two-pointer technique but try your approach on the array I gave. Your approach works only if the array elements are distinct.

Comment: @risingStark Once the array is sorted, it is easy to remove duplicates. If we want to count all solutions, including duplicates, then effectively some logic must be added. Nothing in the post suggesting there will be duplicates ... My previous comment was for OP!

Comment: @writedowntheanswer Will the input array contain duplicates?

Comment: @risingStark The conditions are 1<=n<=100,000 and not duplicate

Comment: sorry i didn't comment conditions it's my fault

Comment: @Damien sir i try to solve that but can't well ' while(i<n){
        if(m==data[i]+data[n]){
            count++;
            i++;
            data[n]=data[n-1];
        }
        else if(m>data[i]+data[n]){
            i++;
        }
    }' is it right?

Comment: @writedowntheanswer Not exactly. You have to play with the indices only, No need to modify the array. Please have a look at my answer, and please test it carefully, then give me a feedback on the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple two-pointer technique, after sorting.
It will work as it is because there is no duplicate.

In practice, two indices are used, one from the start of the array, one from the end of the array. We increase the first or decrease the second one, depending on the value of the sum.

Complexity: O(n logn) for sorting, and O(n) for the second step.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int compare_ints(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    int arg1 = *(const int*)a;
    int arg2 = *(const int*)b;
 
    if (arg1 < arg2) return -1;
    if (arg1 > arg2) return 1;
    return 0;
}

int count_sum (int* A, int n, int target) {
    int count = 0;
    qsort(A, n, sizeof(int), compare_ints);
    int left = 0;
    int right = n-1;
    
    while (left < right) {
        int sum = A[left] + A[right];
        if (sum == target) {
            count++;
            left++;
            right--;
        } else if (sum < target) {
            left++;
        } else {
            right--;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main() {
    int A[] = {8, 2, 7, 5, 3, 1};
    int target = 10;
    int n = sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);
    
    int ans = count_sum (A, n, target);
    printf ("count = %d\n", ans);
    
    return 0;
}
```